# How do I create testcafe selector element when the iframe has only src?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I have a following iframe section which i would like to use for further actions

```
    <div class="addonWrapper"><div class="detailhead mobileonly">   
    <div class="cancelbtn cancelmobileiframebtn" title="Zurück" onclick="closeMobileIFrame()"></div></div>
    <iframe src="https://abcd.php?stage=1&amp;access_token=zrhrhha8b-621bb319cd38d-1348650f57bf2b8d70fbc84d95b747ab" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"></iframe>
    </div>
```

i have tried to do something like this.

```
this.iframeM = Selector('iframe').withAttribute(
            'src',
            'https://abcd.php?stage=1&amp;access_token=zrhrhha8b-621bb319cd38d-1348650f57bf2b8d70fbc84d95b747ab'
        );
```

then in the test

```
await t.switchToIframe(mPage.iframeM);
```

But its not successful. I keep getting the error "The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.!"

What is the best way to identify the iframe in this case where only src is available. Help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following ?

1. Use regular expression instead of the exact value of the attribute

`https:\/\/abcd.php\?stage=1.*`

```
this.iframeM = Selector('iframe').withAttribute(
            'src',/https:\/\/abcd.php\?stage=1.*/
        );
```

Reference : [Selector with .withAttribute Method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402742/reference/test-api/selector/withattribute)

2. Increase the timeout value for iFrame
   Reference : [Increase the timeout value for the iFrame](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402681/reference/test-api/testcontroller/switchtoiframe#wait-until-an-iframe-is-loaded)
3. Run the test in debug mode
   Run the test in debug mode and execute the iFrame specific code when the frame is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In v2.4.0, you can use the [Visual Selector Debugger](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404288/guides/intermediate-guides/visual-selector-debugger). This feature includes a selector generator. Unfortunately, you won't be able to generate a selector inside an iframe yet, but you can do this for the iframe itself.